# how to validate the API requested from valid source in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to api development, my client required to check or restrict the api call from valid sources

api will throw an error when requested from the postman or other like took in the production. Looking for a solution in laravel 6.*

Comment: Define "valid source". Are we talking about specific sources that always comes from the same IP's? Please edit the question to include a _proper_ explanation of what you'tr trying to do and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

**You should first define valid sources.
There is various way to restrict your api call like -**

1. From where api should be called from web, api-postman, etc.
2. From which IP address. You can limit the api call from one IP address using throttle middleware. (for security purpose)
3. You can put encryption on your api call so that only your application can call that API.
4. You should always use Authorization on API to secure api response.
5. Always use Server Side Validation on every api just like you do in your POST or GET request.

Answer (score -1):

You can check:

1. UserAgent Header in the request & allow certain user-agent as per your choice.
2. You can check the refer header field to identify the the domain from where the endpoint request is made..

Comment: Neither of those are good metrics for allowing/blocking requests. The user agent is literally created by the client and can therefor easily be manipulated. And the "referer" header doesn't always exist (and can be manipulated as well).